# Reference to KCGIMageAlphaFirst is ambiguous iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I have developed an application it worked fine, I have released a version to client , he came back with some changes in UI, now when I opened that project after 15 days to complete the changes I am getting Reference to 'X' is ambiguous error, that X is mainly KCGImage related properties like the one mentioned in Title. I am using Xcode and used cocoa pods for adding two frameworks. I have tried the other questions on this category but they are related to xcode4 and Xcode5. I have different check points of code which worked fine previously, but now I tried with 3 old versions of code, all are giving the same problem, if you can provide some insights on this, would be helpful thank you.